# Adding two xmls. Working with XSLT transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt, mule

I am looking for solution for a scenario which is troubling me  a lot.

I am working on mule 3.3.

I have some incoming XML and a second XMLcoming from the enricher.

Now the xml from the enricher is to be added into my input XML.

My flow looks like below (abstract)

```
<flow name="main" >
    <file:inbound  ....> 
    <enricher target="#[variable:myProperty]">
        <vm:outbound .... />
    </enricher>

    <xslt transformer .... />
    .......
    .......
    <file:outbound ..>
</flow>
```

My Mule Flow part and the XSL  as given below

```
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer   maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"   xsl-file="C:\NSBTransformerXSL.xsl" outputEncoding="UTF-8" doc:name="XSLT">


        <mulexml:context-property key="RefXML"  value="#[header:INVOCATION:RefXML]" />
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
```

My XSL is given below

```
<xsl:param name="RefXML"></xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">        
    <xsl:copy   >             
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                  
    </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TXRequest">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>         
        <xsl:copy-of select="$RefXML"/>                         
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XSL-T transformer and pass the XML fragment you got from the enricher to your XSL as a named parameter.

That way you can easily combine two XMLs.

The correct way of doing this would be to parse `RefXML` as a DOM element, then pass it as an XSL parameter, but [a bug in Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6501) prevents this :(

So the only option is a verbatim copy of the string value of `RefXML`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$RefXML" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Not super satisfying but it works.

Comment: I have tried that. But the problem here is the XML fragment which I am passing as a named parameter to my final XSL is not working properly.    In the output XML it showed like..     <MyXML>  
 <t1>Some Text</t1>  
 <t2> Some Text </t2> 
 &lt;T3 id="new" &gt;  
  &lt;T31 tc="inner" /&gt;
 /&lt;T3&gt;
 
 ......
</MyXML>

Comment: I have tried that. But the problem here is the XML fragment which I am passing as a named parameter to my final XSL is not working properly. In the output XML it showed like.. <MyXML> <t1>Some Text</t1> <t2> Some Text </t2> &lt;T3 id="new" &gt; &lt;T31 tc="inner" /&gt; &lt;/T3&gt; ...... </MyXML>                 Where as the expected answer is as below.      <MyXML>  
 <t1>Some Text</t1>  
 <t2> Some Text </t2> 
 <T3 id="new" >  
  <T31 tc="inner" />
 </T3>
 
 ......
</MyXML>

Comment: I have edited my question and added my mule flow and xsl parts.

Comment: I have reviewed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question or problem is.  I believe it's that you're having a hard time combining the two xml pieces.

If this is the case might I suggest using a Datamapper -http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/DataMapper+Transformer+Reference

Trying being specific in your question, also people like to ask what version of mule you're working in. (Wish I could of put this post as a comment)

Comment: Yes I have problem adding two xml pieces, one read from file inbound and other recieved from the enricher.   I am sorry that I forgot to mention the version of mule. I am working with Mule 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [saxon:parse extension](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse.html). The following works for me:

```
<xsl:param name="RefXMLIn"/>
<xsl:variable name="RefXML" select="saxon:parse($RefXMLIn)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
```

It renames the parameter that receives the XML as text and fills the original variable with the result of the parse function.

This extension is Saxon specific, however Saxon is the default XML library that comes with Mule.